# Javascript error when using Gulp Uglify with js array

Tags: javascript, gulp, syntax-error

I'm getting the following error when running uglify in Gulp. Not getting an error when calling this same code in script in head of document. Please advise how to fix error.

Error in terminal:

```
 { SyntaxError: Unexpected token punc «,», expected punc «:»
     at JS_Parse_Error.get (eval at <anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site.com/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:0), <anonymous>:86:23)
     at formatError (util.js:644:15)
     at formatValue (util.js:550:18)
     at formatProperty (util.js:790:15)
     at util.js:650:12
     at Array.map (native)
     at formatObject (util.js:649:15)
     at formatValue (util.js:589:16)
     at inspect (util.js:183:10)
     at exports.format (util.js:69:24)
   message: 'Unexpected token punc «,», expected punc «:»',
   filename: 'jquery.main.js',
   line: 104,
   col: 18,
   pos: 2671 },
plugin: 'gulp-uglify',
fileName: '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site.com/src_assets/js/jquery.main.js',
showStack: false }
```

Javascript Error on line: 104 is referring to line `playerVars,`:

```
  window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
      playerVars = { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0, 'rel': 0, 'showinfo': 0, 'loop': 1, 'modestbranding': 1 };

      return new YT.Player('youtubeVideoPlayer', {
        height: playerHeight,
        width: playerWidth,
        videoId: player.data('video-id'),
        playerVars,
        events: {
            onReady: function(e) {
              frame = holder.find('iframe');
              e.target.mute();
              resizeHandler();
            }
          }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Is that related to the declariton of 

playerVars ?

Use const playerVars  = { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0, 'rel': 0, 'showinfo': 0, 'loop': 1, 'modestbranding': 1 };

Answer (score 2):

Uglify apparently doesn't understand the ES6 shorthand `playerVars` for `playerVars: playerVars`.

I think you can resolve this by installing [uglify-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es). Or just replace the shorthand with the traditional syntax.